# "NFS <server> not responding still trying" error timestamp

Tags: solaris, nfs

Sometime while my putty session is connected to server, it gets this NFS error.
Note the server is Solaris 11 based.

```
NFS server <server> not responding still trying
NFS server <server> not responding still trying
NFS server <server> not responding still trying
NFS server <server> not responding still trying
```

.
.
After some tries it becomes ok.

```
NFS server <server> ok
NFS server <server> ok
NFS server <server> ok
```

Is there a way by which I can get to know the exact timestamp when this error occurs? 
I am quite new to Unix and could not find a way to get the timestamp.

Regards
Jim

Comment: Look in `/var/adm/messages`, where the messages should appear along with their timestamp.

Comment: Thanks @Flup. That was the right place and I see the error messages with timestamp.

Comment: Lovely, I'll post that as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The errors will be in `/var/adm/messages` along with their timestamps.